# How to store the text in a string variable from a text file in the asset directory?

Tags: xamarin.android

I am doing some test with xamarin android. I have a text file in the asset folder, that I know how to access to this file:

```
using (Stream myFile= Assets.Open("myFile.txt"))
{
    using (FileStream myDestinationFile= File.Create("myDestinationPath"))
    {
        myFile.CopyTo(myDestinationFile);
    }
}
```

With this code, I can copy the file to another location, for example, "Personal", so I can edit the file because I know that I can't edit the files in the assets folder.

But I would like to pass the information of the text file directly to a string variable, beacause I don't need to edit the file, just to access to the information and pass this string as parameter of a method.

Is it possible to set a string variable with the information of the text file of the asset folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I would like to pass the information of the text file directly to a string variable, beacause I don't need to edit the file, just to access to the information and pass this string as parameter of a method.

If you want to pass the string from the text file in Assect folder, you could use `AssetManager`.

Text file:

[image]

Set the Build Action to AndroidAssect:

[image]

Code:

```
// Create a new TextView and set it as our view
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);

        // Read the contents of our asset
        string content;
        AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assets.Open("TextFile1.txt")))
        {
            content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        // Set TextView.Text to our asset content
        tv.Text = content;


        SetContentView(tv);
```

Result:

[image]